# How to find the function name, which is going to be invoked?

Tags: visual-c++

I got:

```
InvokeHelper(0x18, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_I4, (void*)&result, NULL);
```

How to get function name, if we have the object method or property 
specified by dwDispID = 0x18?

```
void AFX_CDECL InvokeHelper(
   DISPID dwDispID,
   WORD wFlags,
   VARTYPE vtRet,
   void* pvRet,
   const BYTE* pbParamInfo,
   ... 
);
```

Comment: I don't know the function name, that is what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple sample of how to fetch the name

```
void CTestDlg::OnTypeinfo()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    COleDispatchDriver sc;

    sc.CreateDispatch("Omtool.ServConnect.1"); // change for your type

    CComPtr<ITypeInfo> pti;

    hr = sc.m_lpDispatch->GetTypeInfo(0, GetUserDefaultLCID(), &pti);
    ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    CComBSTR bstrName;
    UINT nCount = 0;

    hr = pti->GetNames(0x2, &bstrName, 1, &nCount); // change 0x2 for your ID
    ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to get a `ITypeInfo` interface on the object (`CWnd::GetControlUnknown`, `IUnknown::QueryInterface`). Then you can use the `ITypeInfo::GetNames` function with your member ID (`0x18`) to get the name of the method.

Comment: Sorry, I have not the time right now to dig into MSDN to get the syntax right. I don't want to publish examples that do not work. Either you try to figure it out by sourself (search for the mentioned functions/interfaces in MSDN) or you'll have to wait until tomorrow :-) ...